# How does Yii know CWebApplication exists?

Tags: yii, bootstrapping

I was trying to unravel a little bit how Yii initializes for my own educational purposes. But I got stuck very much at the beginning. So here it goes:

**I understand how in index.php two files are being assigned to a variable:**

```
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/../protected/config/main.php';
```

**I understand how the first file gets included by including the variable `$yii`:**

```
require_once($yii);
```

**I understand that a call is made to a static method in the empty** `class Yii{}` **(found in yii.php) which is an extension of the** `class Yiibase{}` **(found in Yiibase.php) and that the variable** `$config` **is passed to that that method:**

```
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

**What I don't understand is:**

- what `->run()` does and where it comes from?
- How in the method createWebApplication an object (`CWebApplication`) is created that I don't see included in a file up until that point. How does it know the `class CWebApplication{}` exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createWebApplication()` [#](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/YiiBase.php#L98) just returns `new CWebApplication($config)` [#](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/YiiBase.php#L125) which has the `run()` [#](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/base/CApplication.php#L158) method and this class can be easily autoimported by an earlier registration of an autoloder [#](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/YiiBase.php#L854).

Comment: Aaaah thanks a lot! Now I understand how that part of the bootstrap works!